# Why do I have to use PhantomData? What is it doing in this case?

Tags: generics, rust

The following code compiles only if I include the line marked with "???". If I remove the line I get lots of error message about parameter "S" never being used. I stumbled upon this "problem" in a larger scenario and had a hard time pinning it down. As far as I can tell, it happens due to the circular references between the types.

```
struct Question<S> {
    x: Vec<AnswerRef<S>>,
    _y: PhantomData<S>  // ???
}

struct QuestionRef<S>(Rc<Question<S>>);

struct Answer<S> {
    x: Option<QuestionRef<S>>
}

struct AnswerRef<S>(Rc<Answer<S>>);
```

Adding the `PhantomData` solves the problem, but I don't understand why. I don't see why it should make a difference in this case. Can somebody explain it to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Rust compiler is quite clever here, it detects the cyclic usage of `S` and determines that you can remove it completely to get the same data structures. You can use `PhantomData` to "use" type parameters that are unused otherwise as they are here.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried to make incremental changes, as I'm still quite new to Rust. If I would have finished my example (i.e. use the S) it would have worked, but this way I learned something new. ;-)

Comment: It does that by determining that this parameter is bivariant, and so it is unused.